# Axios request to cloudinary client side CORS policy error

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I am currently trying to post to cloudinary via client side and I am getting the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dd5gloppf/add/image/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I am basically trying to post to cloudinary and get back the url of the image I am posting to the api so i can eventually send it to my server and store it on my back end.  does anyone know what i am currently doing wrong?

I am unsure of how to deal with a CORS policy error from the client-side. My code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dd5gloppf/add/image/upload'
  const preset = 'ml_default'

  const onChange = e => {
    setImage(e.target.files[0])
  }

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    console.log('im running')
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', image)
    formData.append('upload_preset', preset)
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      const res = await axios.post(url, formData, {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })

      console.log(res)
      const imageUrl = res.data.secure_url
      console.log(imageUrl)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='file-field input-field'>
        <div className='btn'>
          <span>Browse</span>
          <input type='file' name='image' onChange={onChange} />
        </div>
        <div className='file-path-wrapper'>
          <input className='file-path validate' type='text' />
        </div>
        <button onClick={onSubmit} className='btn center'>
          upload
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading to Cloudinary is definitely possible to do from the client. As the developer behind Cloudinary's [Upload Widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) I can assure you that :)

However, if you'd like a "signed" upload. Meaning a secure way to ensure only "authorized" code can upload to your Cloudinary account, you do need a server component as explained [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#signed_uploads) and [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/signatures).

However, for demo/dev purposes, you can very easily upload to Cloudinary from the browser.

Check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cookies-xeu6g?file=/src/App.js).

*** EDIT

To enable unsigned uploads, youd need to change your cloud settings (settings -> Upload -> Upload presets).

[image]

You will then have an unsigned upload preset, its name will be the string you use in the code

Comment: Thank you! How should the upload preset look if I was to follow your codebox example

Comment: @CodeMonkey ive updated the answer with the info you need

Comment: @poeticGeek I am getting this error, when trying to use the upload widget. How we can solve this issue to load the script properly? "Access to script at 'https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And when the script does not load, it does not work and causes this issue
"Uncaught TypeError: widget.open is not a function"

Comment: I was using crossorigin="anonymous" in the widget loading, that's why it was given the CORS issue, removing the crossorigin solves the problem